# simple way to recognize/identify a gesture

Tags: cocoa, gesture, gesture-recognition

Hi I implemented this function and i can hand the gestures but how can i recognize what gesture is which?for example simple move to left or right?

my code for handling:

```
/*this function is made to handel finger gesture and flip the view to other account*/
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{



    FirstViewController *screen = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    screen.myArray = myArray;    
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];

}
```

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it very much depends on what gesture you want to trap. If it is a simple pinch, swipe tap etc then you should probably use one of Apple new (in 3.2) convenience classes described in [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html).

Using these, trapping a gesture is as simple as adding something like the following to your code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleFingerDTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleDoubleTap:)];
doubleFingerDTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleFingerDTap];
```

and then implementing the method to process the gesture when it is found:

```
- (void)handleDoubleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
      //Do something here
}
```

This will trap a double tap.